# How to set the encoded string data to MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, image, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have to set the following string data to body of (SMS) MFMessageComposeViewController, can any one help me  to get the solution ?

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what problems do you have?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand the question the problem is how to fill sms body. There is an exelent solution for this: [Click here!](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-send-an-sms-progammatically.html)

And of course [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)